# Get employees who received a raise in 2 consecutive years

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to Get employees who received a raise in 2 consecutive years, in this case employee `1000` is the right answer.

here is the data and the sql i have tried.

| EID | SALARY | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 10,000 | 2016 |
| 1000 | 7,500 | 2015 |
| 1000 | 6,000 | 2014 |
| 1001 | 8,000 | 2016 |
| 1001 | 7,500 | 2015 |
| 1002 | 7,500 | 2016 |
| 1002 | 7,500 | 2015 |
| 1002 | 5,000 | 2014 |
| 1003 | 6,000 | 2016 |
| 1003 | 7,000 | 2015 |
| 1003 | 5,000 | 2014 |

i have used following code however it gets only row number by EID and not calcualtion of last year and present year, i need to find employee who got raise in 2 consecutive years.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QefZC.png)

```
select * , 
       row_number() over(partition by eid order by salary and year desc)as rn 
from gs;
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL? MySQL 8+ has functionality not present in MySQL 5.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the `LEAD` window function that compute the two consecutive previous value of the salary. Then you can check how many employees have at least one row with `salary1 < salary2 < salary3`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    eid
FROM (
    SELECT
        eid,
        year,
        salary,
        (LEAD(salary, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY eid ORDER BY year DESC)) AS prev_salary1,
        (LEAD(salary, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY eid ORDER BY year DESC)) AS prev_salary2
    FROM 
        employees
    ) consecutive3
WHERE 
    salary > prev_salary1
AND     
    prev_salary1 > prev_salary2
```

The assumption is that there are no missing years for which a salary of a dependent was not recorded.

Here's the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c0d8a1deec8e77bb32a173656c3e386.

---

**EDIT: Detailed explanation**

Let's do the example of Jennifer, who has worked for five years and got these salaries:

- 2018 -> 65000
- 2017 -> 55000
- 2016 -> 50000

She's a candidate for being selected as her salary was raised three times consecutively.

**1.** `LEAD(salary, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY eid ORDER BY year DESC)`

Allows you to get the salary for year "Y" and the salary for year "Y-1":

("year" -> "salary", "previous_salary")

- 2018 -> 65000 , 55000
- 2017 -> 55000 , 50000
- 2016 -> 50000 , NULL

**2.** `LEAD(salary, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY eid ORDER BY year DESC)`

Allows you to get the salary for year "Y" and the salary for year "Y-1":

("year" -> "salary", "previous_salary", "previous_salary_by_2_years")

- 2018 -> 65000 , 55000 , 50000
- 2017 -> 55000 , 50000 , NULL
- 2016 -> 50000 , NULL  , NULL

**3.** `WHERE salary > prev_salary1 AND prev_salary1 > prev_salary2`

Some filtering on the employees who

- have their year3 salary higher than their year2 salary (`salary > prev_salary1`)
- have their year2 salary higher than their year1 salary (`prev_salary1 > prev_salary2`)

Comment: can you plese explain code?

Comment: updated the answer with a detailed explanation of the process behind the query @user18576551

Comment: Will return employees with two pay rises, not necessarily in two Consecutive years.  `300->400->400->500` would meet this query's criteria.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the catch @MatBailie. I've updated the code to catch also that case.

Comment: The not null check is redundant. If the value is null, the greater than check can't be true.

Comment: Includes edge case if an EID was gone a year and return to a higher salary.  (2013,$5000), (2014,$6000), (2016,$9000)  would return true but no record in 2015.  eid shouldn't be included I would think but is.  but overall good.

Comment: Exactly: it's written in the assumptions @xQbert. A solution that does include that detail would be far more complex than this one, but if I were a company, and my employee went away and came back later, I wouldn't assign them the same employee id I guess... I'll leave that to the the person who wrote the question to decide in case. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this has already been answered but here is my take using the lag function to determine if there was an increase from the previous year and ran that twice.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        t2.*,
        LAG(increase) over (partition by eid order by year) AS increaseNextYear
    FROM (
        SELECT
            t1.*,
            COALESCE(salary - LAG(salary) over (partition by eid order by year), 0) > 0 AS increase
        FROM tbl_test t1
    ) as t2
) t3 where increase AND increaseNextYear
```

Comment: Lag takes an optional parameter for how many rows back to look. Using that you can lag twice in the same query, no need for a sub-query.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag

Comment: Nice I’ll remember that one!

Answer (score 1):

```
with
  dates as
(
  select
    a.*,
    dense_rank() OVER (
      partition by eid
          order by year desc, salary
      )
        as rn, 
    case
      when 
        lead(salary,2)over(partition  by eid order by year, salary)
        >
        lead(salary,1)over(partition by eid order by year, salary)
      and  
        lead(salary,1)over(partition by eid order by year, salary)
        >
        salary
      then
        1
      else
        0
    end
      as flag
  from
    employees a
)
select
  eid
from
  dates
where
      rn   = 3
  and flag = 1
```

Comment: @MatBailie Thank you so much for editing the code.i ve try to beautify the code but i don t know how.Thank you

Comment: The row number check is a problem. This only catches cases where the two most recent years were pay rises. What about the sequence `300->400->500->500`? The conditions are only true in row 4.

Answer (score 1):

Not a beautiful query, but straight-forward: find employees who had a salary in a year where the salary in the previous year was lower and the salary in the year before that even lower. Using `LAG` is more elegant, but I thought I'd throw this in, just to show an alternative.

```
select *
from employee
where exists
(
  select null
  from gs
  where gs.eid = employee.id
  and exists
  (
    select null
    from gs prev
    where prev.eid = gs.eid
    and prev.year = gs.year - 1
    and prev.salary < gs.salary
    and exists
    (
      select null
      from gs prevprev
      where prevprev.eid = prev.eid
      and prevprev.year = prev.year - 1
      and prevprev.salary < prev.salary
    )
  )
);
```

Same thing with a join:

```
select *
from employee
where exists
(
  select null
  from gs
  join gs prev on prev.eid = gs.eid
              and prev.year = gs.year - 1
              and prev.salary < gs.salary
  join gs prevprev on prevprev.eid = prev.eid
                  and prevprev.year = prev.year - 1
                  and prevprev.salary < prev.salary
  where gs.eid = employee.id
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For versions prior to 8.0 (mine is 5.7) which lack the cutting edge features of the newer one, I tried a procedure to accomplish the job. First and foremost, get all the eid which have no less than three years' salary record, which is the minimum requirement of the consecutive bonus. The rest is to fetch and compare using a cursor from the eid pool. The result is stored in a temporary table `t` .

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists lucky_emp//
create procedure lucky_emp()
begin
declare old_eid int default 0;
declare old_salary int;
declare new_eid int ;
declare new_salary int;
declare bonus_year int;
declare fin bool default false;
declare c cursor for select eid,salary from salary where eid in(select eid from salary group by eid having count(eid)>=3) order by eid,year;
declare continue handler for not found set fin=true;
drop temporary table if exists t ;
create temporary table t (t_eid int);
open c;
lp:loop
    fetch c into new_eid ,new_salary;
    if fin=true then
        leave lp;
    end if;
    if new_eid !=old_eid then
        set old_eid=new_eid,old_salary=0,bonus_year=0;
    end if;
    if new_salary> old_salary then
        set bonus_year=bonus_year+1,old_salary=new_salary;
    else 
        set bonus_year=0;
    end if;

    if bonus_year=3 and new_eid not in(select t_eid from t) then
        insert t values(new_eid);
    end if;

end loop lp;

end// 
delimiter ;
select * from t ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.*, b.prev_sal1, b.prev_sal2
from employees a
join (
     Select eid ,year,
     lag(salary,1) over (partition by eid order by year) as prev_sal1,
     lag(salary,2) over (partition by eid order by year) as prev_sal2
     from employees ) b
on a.eid=b.eid
and a.year = b.year
where salary>prev_sal1 and prev_sal1>prev_sal2
```

fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/rfGv31zM

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).